# Firebase detecting connection state & Simultaneous connections to realtimeDB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does listening to the client's connection state using
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state count as a "simultaneous connection" to the realtime database

```
let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(".info/connected")
connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool where connected {
        print("Connected")
    } else {
        print("Not connected")
    }
})
```

And lastly, reading the documentation I'm confused as to whether this observer pings the RealTimeDB at all or if its a client side check on its connectivity status. This confusion comes from the word 'client' in this particular docs sentence "Firebase Realtime Database ***clients*** provide a special location at /.info/connected which is updated every time the client's connection state changes." Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any client that is connected to the Firebase servers counts as a connection. If you're listening to `/.info/connected` you are asking to stay connected to the Firebase servers, so it indeed counts as a connection.

If you want to be certain about such a thing, you can easily:

1. attach a listener in a little client-side browser script (e.g. jsfiddle/jsbin)
2. open that script in multiple browsers
3. check the Database > Usage > Connections chart in your Firebase Console